# Find ColumnDefinition Enum or Constants

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, constants

I am looking a class that will contain the constants or enum for JPA columnDefinition.

Ex:

```
public class MyEntity {

    @JoinColumn(name = "my_value", columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private Integer myValue;

    // some code...
}
```

I'm looking to replace this:

```
"BIGINT" -> ColumnDefinition.BIGINT
```

I'm using JPA/Hibernate and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define a class with some `public static final String BIGINT="BIGINT"` -like fields.
2. Alternatively, add the postgres JDBC driver to your classpath and check if you find anything there.